# Embedded - SIM7600E not responding to any AT commands

Tags: embedded, iot, gsm

I have sim7600E on my project PCB and I am using STM32F103 to communicate with it, I have a level logic level shifter that shifts 3.3V UART down to 1.8V UART. I used a digital analyzer to confirm that the message (for example AT\r\n) is indeed arriving at the RX pin of SIM7600E. I can also confirm that the PWR signal of the module is HIGH and I have also inserted a sim card in the sim slot and the NET light is flashing.

I am quite lost because I have searched the internet for answers and couldn't find any.

Sorry for the lack of information but I really have nothing else to provide.

If anyone has had any experience with sim7600e and could provide me with some guidance it will be extremely appreciated,

Comment: What makes you think it's a software problem? How did you for example ground the various boards together?

Comment: Its a custom built PCB that I designed and assembled. I followed the guides regarding the PWR_KEY as well, and I connected it to GND. That's the thing I don't entirely know whether its truly the problem of a software. Thats the problem in this field - Embedded Engineering. I am hoping someone who had similar issue could reach me out.

Comment: If you can share details like schematic and layout, the question might be more suitable for https://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it wasn't a software issue, there was a problem with logic level converter (3.3v to 1.8v)